# Joining tables with ` `

Tags: mysql

Having some issues joining tables. I think my syntax is wrong due to having to call the column names with `` I think it should be an easy fix. When I call it gives me an error code 1052. Column 'Brand.Name' in field is ambiguous.

```
select a.`Brand.Name`, f.`pH`, a.`CO2.Bright.Level`
from airtest a
join fermentation f 
using(`MyUnknownColumn`)
where `Brand.Name` like "%IPA%";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss table name in `WHERE`  clause, it should be:

`where a.'Brand.Name' like "%IPA%"`